# What happens if I jump with crew members away on another ship?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

What happens if I jump with crew members teleported away on another ship? I've never dared try.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

They die. Same when the ship is destroyed when they are still boarding it. I have tried it sadly. :(

The game does warn you if you try to jump away before you gather your crew. But the game doesn't warn if you teleport crew unto a ship without life support.

Your crew is also gone when the enemy ship jumps away.

Comment: What is with all these upvotes? Crew died people! Have some respect!

Comment: I like to think they carry on, surrender to the other crew.  Become slaves. Someday the escape and settle on a nice planet. Eventually starting a family and struggling to survive in a galaxy torn by war. But they'll always remember the day they had a chance to turn the tide of war. That day they were on a very important mission. The same day you left them behind.

Comment: It's also sad to see them FTL away with your boarding crew. They are lost forever :(